# Flutter Web: MaterialApp Title changes every time I pop back

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Im building a personal website and everytime I pop back from Projects or Blog Page to my home page the Material App changes from the title i initially put it to the name of the folder carpet of the project. I still don't understand why this happens, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I'm using the Fluro package for my navigation route.

Image representation of how the MaterialApp Title changes

[Blog Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnX3x.png) =>[Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnzSv.png)

blog_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BlogPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BlogPageState createState() => _BlogPageState();
}

class _BlogPageState extends State<BlogPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async => true,
        child: Center(
          child: FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: 0.8,
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Hello Stranger!',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webapp/router.dart';

void main() {
  FluroRouter.setupRouter();
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Personal Website',
      initialRoute: 'home',
      onGenerateRoute: FluroRouter.router.generator,
    );
  }
}
```

home_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart' show timeDilation;
import 'package:webapp/widgets/social_media.dart';
import 'package:webapp/widgets/wave_body.dart';
import 'package:webapp/widgets/custom_button_border.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();

  HomePage() {
    timeDilation = 1.0;
  }
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = new Size(
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    );
    return DesktopLayout();
  }
}

class DesktopLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const DesktopLayout({
    Key key,
    @required this.size,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Size size;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(47, 66, 83, 1.0),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Flexible(
            flex: 3,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: ProfessionalSocialMedia(),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: PersonalSocialMedia(),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 15.0,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              CustomButtonBorder(
                stringText: 'Projects',
                size: size,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'project');
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 50.0,
              ),
              CustomButtonBorder(
                stringText: 'Blog',
                size: size,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'blog');
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
          Stack(
            children: [
              WaveBody(
                size: size,
                xOffset: 0,
                yOffset: 0,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(21, 160, 132, 1.0),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This could be related to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35719

Answer (score 0):

The Fluro package could be easily be using the **[Title Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Title-class.html)** which changes the Tab name.

That Widget takes a "title (String)" and a "color (Color)" and will update the name over the Tab.

If you're only using Flutter Web you can take advantage of the http class and also replace your url to match your title:

```dart
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    window.history.pushState(null, 'Blog Page', 'blog-page');
  }
```

That will update your URL to "https://my-url.com/blog-page" and adding the Title Widget your tab will say "Blog Page" as well.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Title(
        title: 'Blog Page',
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

If by any reason you also need Mobile, change your: import 'dart:html'; for the library "universal_html": https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html